# WH_MOUSE_LL not responding to injected events

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, mouseevent, hook

Similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174512/wh-mouse-ll-hook-doesnt-get-called-for-injected-events-mouse-event-sendinput), we are using `SendInput / mouse_event / SetCursorPos` to programmatically move the mouse and send mouse clicks. We also want to capture all the mouse events on the machine using `WH_MOUSE_LL` windows hooks. We make use of the [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which includes a flags property that is used specifically for identifying injected mouse events. However, our callback is never called with injected events.

```
var threadId = 0U;
var moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle("user32");

IntPtr hookId = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, ourCallback, moduleHandle, threadId);

if (hookId == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    log.Error("Could not start getting global mouse messages.");

    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
}
```

Our `hookId` is never `IntPtr.Zero` and removing it with `UnhookWindowsHookEx` succeeds meaning the hook did indeed exist.

Why are we not receiving the events generated by `SendInput / mouse_event / SetCursorPos`?

Comment: It makes very little sense to use all three methods to move the mouse.  Which makes it likely that you are actually just using SetCursorPos(), it does *not* trigger the hook.

Comment: We don't use all three, but we've tried all three. We only use one at a time haha, sorry if that wasn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `SetWindowsHookEx` like this:

```
private delegate IntPtr WindowHookHandler(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private static WindowHookHandler MouseHookHandler = myCallbackFunction;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, WindowHookHandler lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

private static IntPtr MouseHook = IntPtr.Zero;

private static IntPtr SetHook(int hookId, WindowHookHandler callbackFunc)
{
    using (System.Diagnostics.Process curProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        using (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(hookId, callbackFunc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }
}

private static void SomeFunction()
{
    MouseHook = SetHook(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookHandler);

    // message loop here
    // waiting for events

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
}

private static IntPtr myCallbackFunction(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    // do something here

    // ALWAYS return like this!
    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I have tried to test the flags for `LLMHF_INJECTED`, but it never worked.
I used the `dwExtraInfo` field instead. If you are creating an event, put some unique data there, and in the event listener watch for these data.